# How to set privacy settings while posting on a facebook feed, using FB.ui()

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I would like to submit a post to Facebook that will be visible to a specific list of friends only. I know that it is possible to set a `privacy` property for that, as specified on [Facebook's Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/), but I need to use the `FB.ui()` so that the user can preview the post and update its message.

That's the code I use:

```
    FB.ui({
            method: 'feed',
            message: text,
            name: name,
            link: link,
            picture: picture,
            caption: text,
            description: description,
            privacy: {value: "CUSTOM", friends: "SOME_FRIENDS", allow:"666666"}
        }
    );
```

This code works but the `privacy` property seems to be ignored, as my default privacy settings are applied to this post...

Is there a way to set this `privacy` property from the FB.ui() function?

Answer (score 1):

When using the FB.ui, the user has the option to set the privacy settings on their own (the lock in the bottom of the window) and so Facebook does not allow you to override the users default privacy option.

Comment: That makes sense. However, I would like is to restrict the post to a list of users that are registered on our application. Isn't it possible to apply this restriction by updating the post after using FB.ui? Or should I use the graph API instead?

Comment: Post's aren't editable so you would have to try using the graph api, although I'm not sure if you will can pass an arbitrary list of friend id's